# How should I read and write a configuration file for TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I've gathered numbers in a configuration file, and I would like to apply them to buttons. Clicking the button should allow the number to be changed and then re-written to the config file. My current code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

def onChange(i):     
    btn_list[i].config(text='Updating...',bg='red')  
    btn_list[i].grid(in_=root,row=rw[i],column=2)
    ans=tk.simpledialog.askfloat('Updating....', 'What is the current price?')
    if ans:
        btn_list[i].config(text='RM {:,.2f}'.format(ans))
        btn_list[i].config(bg='yellow')
        c=str(ans)
        fw=open('dataUpdate.txt','w')
        fw.write(c)
        fw.close()

root=Tk()

Title=['Item','Unit','Price']
Item=['Kopi O','Teh O','Teh Tarik']
Unit= '1 cup'
cl=[0,1,2]
rw=[1,2,3]
btn_list=[]
fr=open('dataUpdate.txt','r')

with open('dataUpdate.txt') as input_file:
    text=input_file.read()
    strings=text.split()
    number=[float(item) for item in strings]
    print(number)
    fr.close()

for k in range(3):
    btnT1=tk.Button(root,text=Title[k],width=12,bg='light green')
    btnT1.grid(in_=root,row=0,column=cl[k])

for x in range(3):
    btnT2=tk.Button(root,text=Item[x],width=12)
    btnT2.grid(in_=root,row=rw[x],column=0)

for y in range(3):
    btnT3=tk.Button(root,text=Unit,width=12)
    btnT3.grid(in_=root,row=rw[y],column=1)             

for z in range(3):
    btnT4=tk.Button(root,text=('RM {:,.2f}'.format(number[z])),bg='yellow',width=12,\
                command=lambda i=z:onChange(i))
    btnT4.grid(in_=root,row=rw[z],column=2)
    btn_list.append(btnT4)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of my basic configuration file:
[image: dataUpdate.txt]

Comment: This is rather vague to be honest. There are many ways you can layout your config file. It all depends on the structure of your program and preferences. For example, you can have 1 liners delimited by `,` for `split`, segment the file into categories or read everything line by line.

Comment: split method..  I prefer using that.. :) its apply the same principal as read.. how to exactly place/overwrite the input it in the configuration file..

Comment: You would probably update your list of items with the new value. Then overwrite the file with the new list using something like this `file.write(','.join(list))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple example:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog
import configparser
import os.path

def onChange(i):     
    btn_list[i].config(text='Updating...',bg='red')  
    btn_list[i].grid(in_=root,row=rw[i],column=2)
    ans=tk.simpledialog.askfloat('Updating....', 'What is the current price?')
    if ans:
        btn_list[i].config(text='RM {:,.2f}'.format(ans))
        btn_list[i].config(bg='yellow')
        c=str(ans)
        #fw=open('dataUpdate.txt','w')
        #fw.write(c)
        #fw.close()
        #----------------------------------------------
        # Here you can call update(section, key value) 
        update('Section1', 'number%s' % i, c)
        #----------------------------------------------


root=Tk()

Title=['Item','Unit','Price']
Item=['Kopi O','Teh O','Teh Tarik']
Unit= '1 cup'
cl=[0,1,2]
rw=[1,2,3]
btn_list=[]

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

def init():
    'Create a configuration file if does not exist'
    config.add_section('Section1')
    config.set('Section1', 'number1', '1')
    config.set('Section1', 'number2', '0.8')
    config.set('Section1', 'number3', '0.2')
    with open('dataUpdate.cfg', 'w') as output:
        config.write(output)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# check if dataUpdate.cfg exist if not create it   
if not os.path.exists('dataUpdate.cfg'):
    init()

# Read configurations using section and key to get the value
config.read('dataUpdate.cfg')
number = [config.getfloat('Section1', 'number%s' % (i)) for i in range(3)]
#------------------------------------------------------------------------




#------------------------------------------------------------
def update(section, key, value):
    #Update config using section key and the value to change
    #call this when you want to update a value in configuation file
    # with some changes you can save many values in many sections
    config.set(section, key, value )
    with open('dataUpdate.cfg', 'w') as output:
        config.write(output)
#------------------------------------------------------------


for k in range(3):
    btnT1=tk.Button(root,text=Title[k],width=12,bg='light green')
    btnT1.grid(in_=root,row=0,column=cl[k])

for x in range(3):
    btnT2=tk.Button(root,text=Item[x],width=12)
    btnT2.grid(in_=root,row=rw[x],column=0)

for y in range(3):
    btnT3=tk.Button(root,text=Unit,width=12)
    btnT3.grid(in_=root,row=rw[y],column=1)             

for z in range(3):
    btnT4=tk.Button(root,text=('RM {:,.2f}'.format(number[z])),bg='yellow',width=12,\
                command=lambda i=z:onChange(i))
    btnT4.grid(in_=root,row=rw[z],column=2)
    btn_list.append(btnT4)

root.mainloop()
```